You pick $N$ positive integers between $1$ and $M$ without replacement. If you add another number, what is the probability the maximum hasn't changed?
You initially start with all the integers between $1$ and $M$. You then pick $N$ of them randomly, without replacement, to generate a new set of $N$ non-repeating numbers. The maximum of this set is $Z_N$. Say you then add another number from the remaining integers between $1$ and $M$. What is the probability that the maximum of the new set, $Z_{N+1}$, equals $Z_N$?
I believe I am approaching this problem in entirely the wrong way. I have coded up the above scenario to get an empirical estimate of the solution, I have been told the answer is $\frac{N}{N+1}$. What follows is my attempt at solving the problem.
We are trying to calculate $Pr(Z_{N+1}=Z_{N})$. The following is true:
$$
\begin{align}
Pr(Z_{N+1}=Z_{N})&=\sum_{i=1}^{M}Pr((Z_N=i)\cap(Z_{N+1}=i)) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{M}Pr(Z_{N+1}=i|Z_N=i)Pr(Z_N=i) \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align}
$$
We know that $Z_N$ cannot be smaller than $N$, therefore
$$
Pr(Z_{N+1}=Z_{N})=\sum_{i=N+1}^{M}Pr(Z_{N+1}=i|Z_N=i)Pr(Z_N=i) \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
Now, if we refer to the $(N+1)$-th number we draw as $X_{N+1}$, then we can rewrite \eqref{eq2} as
$$
Pr(Z_{N+1}=Z_{N})=\sum_{i=N+1}^{M}Pr(X_{N+1}<i|Z_N=i)Pr(Z_N=i) \tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
For every $i>N+1$, given that $Z_N=i$, we know there are $i-N$ integers below $i$ available to $X_{N+1}$. Given that $X_{N+1}$ is chosen randomly as well,
$$
Pr(X_{N+1}<i|Z_N=i)=\frac{i-N}{M-N} \tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$
Now we need to find the probability mass function for $Z_N$. I will do this by the typical route of getting the cumulative mass function and then getting the pmf from that.
$$
\begin{align}
Pr(Z_N<i)&=\prod_{k=1}^NPr(X_k<i) \\
&=\left(\frac{i-1}{M}\right)^N \tag{5}\label{eq5} \\
Pr(Z_N=i)&=Pr(Z_N<i+1)-Pr(Z_N<i)\\
&=\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N-\left(\frac{i-1}{M}\right)^N \tag{6}\label{eq6}
\end{align}
$$
We can now substitute \eqref{eq4} and \eqref{eq6} into \eqref{eq3} to get the following
$$
\begin{align}
Pr(Z_{N+1}=Z_{N})&=\sum_{i=N+1}^{M}\frac{i-N}{M-N}\left(\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N-\left(\frac{i-1}{M}\right)^N\right) \tag{7}\label{eq7} \\
&=\sum_{i=N+1}^{M}\frac{i-N}{M-N}\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N-\sum_{i=N}^{M-1}\frac{i+1-N}{M-N}\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N \\
&=1-\frac{1}{M-N}\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)^N+\sum_{i=N+1}^{M-1}\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N\left(\frac{i-N-i-1+N}{M-N}\right) \\
&=1-\frac{1}{M-N}\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)^N-\frac{1}{M-N}\sum_{i=N+1}^{M-1}\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N \\
&=1-\frac{1}{M-N}\sum_{i=N}^{M-1}\left(\frac{i}{M}\right)^N \tag{8}\label{eq8}
\end{align}
$$
At this point, I am stuck. I'm not sure if \eqref{eq8} is right, and if it is, I have no idea how to get from that to $\frac{N}{N+1}$.
Three questions:

What is the best way to solve this problem?
Is my answer, \eqref{eq8}, correct?
If so, how do I simplify my result? If not, where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help.

If you add another number less than or equal to the original maximum, then the maximum remains unchanged. Otherwise, the newly added number becomes the new maximum.

@GeoffreyTrang, yes, I agree with that. I try to make use of that in (8). Am I missing a more direct way to come to the answer using that fact?

I might be completely wrong but this problem is saying that if you choose $N+1$ different numbers from $1$ to $N$, then what is the probability that the last one you have chosen is not the largest? Then clearly the probability would be $1-\frac1{N+1}=\frac{N}{N+1}$.

@SaiMehta Aaah that makes sense. Thank you! I hadn't thought of it that way.

@SaiMehta it is correct. You may write it as an answer.

Your work is not correct, for the following reason. You erred when you said
$$
P(Z_N<i)\stackrel{\text{error}}=\prod_{k=1}^NP(X_k<i).
$$
The problem is that since we are sampling without replacement, the variables $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are dependent, so you cannot just multiply the probabilities. Instead,
$$
P(Z_N<i)=\binom{i-1}{N}\Big/\binom{M}{N}.
$$
Indeed, in order to have a maximum of less than $i$, then you need to choose the $N$ numbers from the set $\{1,\dots,i-1\}$, so there are $\binom{i-1}{N}$ favorable cases.
If you wanted, you could redo your calculations with the above correct formula for $P(Z_n<i)$, and then show algebraically that the result is $N/(N+1)$. However, it is easier to argue from symmetry. We know that the maximum among $X_1,\dots,X_N,X_{N+1}$ occurs at a unique entry. By symmetry, each entry is equally likely to be the largest, so each entry has probability $1/(N+1)$ of being the largest. The event $Z_N=Z_{N+1}$ occurs if and only if the maximum is among the first $N$ entries, hence the probability of $N/(N+1)$.
